# What does the product of the covariance matrix by a metric matrix actually mean?

Tags: self-study, pca, interpretation, matrix

> Let be the following data matrice:
>
> $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
>    1 & 0 & 0 \\
>    0 & 0 & 1 \\
>    0 & 1 & 2 \\
>    2 & 1 & 1 \\
>    1 & 1 & 0 \\
>    2 & 3 & 2 
> \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> and the following metric defined by
>
> $$M=\begin{bmatrix}
>    \frac{1}{Var(a)} & 0 & 0\\
>    0 & \frac{1}{Var(a^2)} & 0\\
>    0 & 0 & \frac{1}{Var(a^3)}\\
> \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> If Y is the matrice of centered values, V the covariance matrice and M is the covariance matrice, what may be the meaning of VM?

I calculated the mean $g=(1,1,1)$
\begin{equation*}
V =\frac{1}{n}Y^tY\\
V =\frac{1}{6}\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & -1 & -1 \\
   -1 & -1 & 0 \\
   -1 & 0 & 1 \\
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & -1 \\
   -1 & 2 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & -1\\
   -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2\\
   -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
V=\frac{1}{6}\begin{bmatrix}
   4 & 2 & 0\\
   2 & 6 & 4\\
   0 & 4 & 4\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Furthermore $var(a_i)=\sqrt{\frac{\sum(a_i-y)^2}{n}}$
Which allows us to calculate

- $var(a)=\frac{16}{\sqrt{6}}$
- $var(a^2)=6\sqrt{6}$
- $var(a^3)=\frac{16}{\sqrt{6}}$

Hence we can calculate VM:

\begin{equation*}
VM=\frac{1}{6}\begin{bmatrix}
   4 & 2 & 0\\
   2 & 6 & 4\\
   0 & 4 & 4\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
   \frac{\sqrt{6}}{16} & 0 & 0\\
   0 & \frac{1}{6\sqrt{6}} & 0\\
   0 & 0 & \frac{\sqrt{6}}{16}\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
VM=\frac{1}{6}\begin{bmatrix}
   \sqrt{6} & 0 & 0\\
   0 & \sqrt{6} & 0\\
   0 & 0 & \sqrt{6}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

But I don't know what it represents...
Maybe I made a mistake when calculating this matrice because next, I have to verify that $$\begin{bmatrix}
   1\\
   2\\
   1
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
   1\\
   0\\
   -1
\end{bmatrix}$$

are eigen vectors of $VM$. It fits, they are associated with $\frac{\sqrt{6}}{6}$  but when I try to find the last eigen-vectors I find \begin{bmatrix}
   1\\
   -1\\
   1
\end{bmatrix} associated with the same eigen-value $\frac{\sqrt{6}}{6}$. Yet, in the following question I have to find only two factorial axis (axis wich are not associated with eigen-vales equal to $0$) and none of my eigen-vectors are associated with the eigen-value $0$...

Comment: What is $V$ in your question?

Comment: Is $M$ supposed to have variance of individual variables on the diagonal? So not $a^2$, but $a_2$ etc.?

Comment: @amoeba, sorry, I was wrong in my first comment, the teacher wrote it this way: $a^2$, not $a_2$... I assumed it was the squared sum of the vectors at the second column...

Comment: I think it's better to write it as $a_2$ and $a_3$, because otherwise it reads as if it's $a$ to the second and to the third power. Apart from that, I added [self-study] tag; if you ask questions about homework or textbook exercises, please use this tag. Our policy is to provide "helpful hints" in this case. Finally, your $V$ is not diagonal so $VM$ should also not be diagonal; looks like you have mistake there.

Comment: Also, in English it's not "matrice" but "matrix" :)

Comment: @amoeba, Okay for $a^2$ but how should I understand $a^3$ then?